# Losing pixels values when counting by value

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, ndvi, count, values

I have a script that calculates number of pixels with NDVI values that are higher than 0.3, 0.5 and 0.7.

My code runs with no errors, but it get value 0 and doesn't really count.

what can be the reason?

```
var meanImage=ee.Image(byYear.get[0]);

var gt03 = meanImage.gt(0.3).selfMask().rename('NDVI_gt03');
var gt04 = meanImage.gt(0.5).selfMask().rename('NDVI_gt05');
var gt05 = meanImage.gt(0.7).selfMask().rename('NDVI_gt07');

Map.addLayer(gt03,NDVIcolor,'gt03');
Map.addLayer(gt04,NDVIcolor,'gt05');
Map.addLayer(gt05,NDVIcolor,'gt07');

//count the number of total pixels
var c03 = gt03.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  geometry: geometry,
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  scale: 30,
  });

var c05 = gt05.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  geometry:geometry,
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  scale: 30,
  });

  var c07 = gt07.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  geometry:geometry,
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  scale: 30,
  });
// print the dictionary output
print(c03,'Total Pixels gt 0.3 ');
print(c05,'Total Pixels gt 0.5 ');
print(c07,'Total Pixels gt 0.7 ');
```

[image]

I have tried also to use listOfImages but still got 0.

My end goal is to calculte the number of pixels with the given values for one image.

link for my code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/559d0922b50d67cf01e4d5b03a21666d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you share your assets we can make sure the issue is the way you select the images:

By year is and object of type `imageCollection`, `.get()` won't select images for you. This should work:

```
var meanImage=ee.Image(byYear.first());
var gt03 = meanImage.gt(0.3).selfMask().rename('NDVI_gt03');
var gt05 = meanImage.gt(0.5).selfMask().rename('NDVI_gt05');
var gt07 = meanImage.gt(0.7).selfMask().rename('NDVI_gt07');
//count the number of total pixels
var c03 = gt03.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  geometry: geometry,
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  scale: 30,
  });

var c05 = gt05.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  geometry:geometry,
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  scale: 30,
  });

  var c07 = gt07.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  geometry:geometry,
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  scale: 30,
  });
// print the dictionary output
print(c03,'Total Pixels gt 0.3 ');
print(c05,'Total Pixels gt 0.5 ');
print(c07,'Total Pixels gt 0.7 ');
```

If you want to use `.get()` you'll have to turn the collection into a list first and select the element which you then cast to an `ee.Image` object.

In theory the 0 can also come from the fact there are no pixels in the ranges you define.

// EDIT

If you want to map over the images and return for each image the pixel count, one way of doing it could be like this:

```
    var listOfImages =(byYear.toList(byYear.size()));
    print(listOfImages, 'list')

    var stats = listOfImages.map(function(img){
      var image = ee.Image(img).select('NDVI_mean')

      var c03 = image.gt(0.3).selfMask().reduceRegion({
        reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
        geometry: geometry,
        crs: 'EPSG:4326',
        scale: 30,
      }).values().get(0);

      var c05 = image.gt(0.5).selfMask().reduceRegion({
        reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
        geometry: geometry,
        crs: 'EPSG:4326',
        scale: 30,
      }).values().get(0);

        var c07 = image.gt(0.7).selfMask().reduceRegion({
        reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
        geometry: geometry,
        crs: 'EPSG:4326',
        scale: 30,
      }).values().get(0);

      return image.set('c03', c03).set('c05', c05).set('c07', c07)
    })
print(stats)
```

It is not a very elegant solution, but i'm no sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: it worked when I used first() but I don't want all the images. if you saw the link, I have the list of images as variable listOfImages but when I try to use this to count number if pixels it doesn't work and I get again 0

Comment: I added the .map() version of the answer. It is not an elegant solution but it should work for your purpose. 
Please consider next time to share your tables/assets or provide a script that illustrates your problem with the geometry inside the script

Comment: This code looks great but for some reason I got also empty list and I haven't gotten the number of pixels gt 0.3,0.5 and 0.7 .I liked the idea but don't know why it doesn't work. You can see here my code which suppse to have no geometry https://code.earthengine.google.com/49553ca984ad022b96f5dd0a3ebca9ae

Comment: If you are not going to share your assets I can't help you with your problem: 
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/asset_manager 

Please read the link and ask a new question

Comment: It's over New-Delhi so any polygon you create there is match

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/cf5d03f927dbed5128e828e826277ee4

Not an issue here.

Comment: Thank you. I think I was mistaken between return and print, I thought the return will print it as well.